# How to add navbar links highlight on section scrolling or clicking on it without jquery?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Need to add this to one website and just wanna make sure it's possible to do without jquery. Client needs it done with pure react or some gatsbyjs plugin. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Yu can use regular browser API's with react. In this case the [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) is what you need to fire events on scroll, and react components have an [onMouseOver](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events) synthetic event.